# Where one can find the data on Shorrocks index for the world?

Tags: economy, income

[Shorrocks index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthony_Shorrocks#Shorrocks_index) is an index of estimated income mobility (in other words, how likely is it for someone who was in bottom 20% by income in their country to increase their income in N years to move to other income quartiles than bottom 20%).

I tried googling, but didn't see any obvious sources of actual index results for countries of the world.

Is there a good source of that data?

Comment: I don't have a link for all countries, but my answer on [Skeptics regarding, the rich get richer](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9836/do-the-rich-get-richer-and-the-poor-get-poorer) led me to a Pew study (generational mobility) as well as others that tracked mobility of all quintiles over time.

Comment: This [paper](http://www.ecineq.org/ecineq_ba/papers/Vittori.pdf) examines 4 countries, but I figure you want a larger sample size.

Comment: Here is a wider [selection](http://www.merit.unu.edu/publications/mgsog_wppdf/2010/wp2010-003.pdf)

Comment: @user1873 - this should be made into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In [this paper](https://www.merit.unu.edu/publications/mgsog_wppdf/2010/wp2010-003.pdf) there is an overview of the Shorrocks index for 14 EU countries over the period between 1994 and 2001. I was not able to find anything newer or covering more countries, possibly because calculating such an index is difficult without extensive information about the country's economics.

Comment: I concur that a comprehensive or much broader global index determination is unlikely to exist due to the practical difficulties involved in obtaining the information needed to calculate it.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to find a 2005 paper by Anthony Shorrocks himself that has not only a description/defense of the rationale used in the index but also the equation and raw data for each country under the study.  You can find the paper [linked here](https://www.rrojasdatabank.info/widerconf/Shorrocks.pdf).

Comment: Sorry, this seems to be the wrong the wrong paper by Shorrocks. This paper is for excess shares representation of Gini coefficient from 2005, not on income mobility which is 1978 paper.